# why the character value stores in integer?

Tags: c

now I'm writing down a code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

    {
        int c;
        printf("I'm waiting for a character: ");
        c = getchar();
        printf("I waited d for the '%c' character\n", c);
        return 0;
    }
```

as you see I have declared c as an integer so the value should be in 0-9 but next 3rd line I just used the printf() Conversion Character of char type value. And somehow it worked!!! so what is the reason behind to make it work?

Comment: To make it more interesting, try changing the printf line to `printf("I waited for the %d character\n", c);`.

Comment: An "int" is just a whole number, probably between -2147483648 and +2147483647 depending on your platform. getchar() returns an int. The %c causes printf() to print the character with that value. Characters are, after all, just numbers like everything else.

Comment: *"the value should be in 0-9"*. The value is in `'0'` to `'9'`. Please note that `'0'` is of type `int`. In the typical (but not always) ASCII system used the character `'0'` has the value `48`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in two parts.

You typed

```
c = getchar();
```

But `getchar` clearly returns *characters*, so how can this work?  Well, actually, it works just fine, in part because the return value from `getchar` is actually an `int` (so that it can also return the non-`char` value `EOF`).  So there's no problem here at all.

And then how can you pass an `int` to get printed by `%c`?  Normally when you call `printf` it's important for the type of the argument you pass to properly match the type expected by the format specifier.  (For example, it's a real bug to pass an `int` and try to print it with `%f`.)  But C doesn't always pass types to functions exactly as you write them, sometimes they're converted ("promoted") to a larger, common type.

One of the times these conversions apply (and, in modern C, pretty much the only time) is when you're calling a function that takes a variable number of arguments, like `printf`.  In that case, when you pass an argument of type `char` or `short int`, it's automatically upconverted to `int`.  So printing an `int` value with `%c` is fine.  (The other important promotion is that when you pass a `float`, it's automatically converted to `double`.  So it turns out you can print both `float` and `double` using `%f`.)

In fact, in C, characters really are small integers, so none of this is surprising.  One way to see this is to change your printf call ever so slightly:

```
printf("I waited for the %d character\n", c);
```

Now if you type `A`, it'll tell you it got 65, because in ASCII, the code for capital A is 65.

Comment: Not me, but perhaps "type promotion" in the context of variadic functions like `printf` could be more clear.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, but I don't worry about random downvotes.  (I suspect someone thought that because this question is so basic and so frequent, it shouldn''t have been answered at all.)

Answer (score -1):

in ascii table, any character value has an integer equivalent. so if you put a character value into a integer variable, that will allocate the integer equivalent for that character value.

Comment: C does not guarantee a specific character encoding.

Comment: Only that characters `'0'` to `'9'` shall be consecutive.